# WinSCP - Uploading files from Windows machine to Linux - Error: Timespan overflowed because the duration is too long

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I installed WinSCP from Managed NuGet package.

I am trying to use WinSCP to upload files from Windows to Linux server. I am getting the error as

> Timespan overflowed because the duration is too long.

I have tried the below code to upload the files.

```
public int Upload(
    String HostName, String UserName, String Password, String remotePath,
    String localFilePath)
{
    int result = 0;
    Session session = null;
    try
    {
        // Setup session options               
        SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
        {
            Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
            HostName = HostName,
            UserName = UserName,
            Password = Password,
            Timeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
        };

        using (session = new Session())
        {
            // Connect
            session.Open(sessionOptions);

           // upload files
            TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
            transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Ascii;

            TransferOperationResult transferResult = null;

            transferResult =
                session.PutFiles(localFilePath, remotePath, false, transferOptions);

            // Throw on any error
            transferResult.Check();
            // Print results
            foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Upload of {0} succeeded", transfer.FileName);
            }

        }

        result = 0;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
        result = 1;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (session != null)
        {
            session.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

How to upload file to remote server?

Stack Exception received is:

```
at System.TimeSpan.Add(TimeSpan ts) 
at System.TimeSpan.op_Addition(TimeSpan t1, TimeSpan t2)
at WinSCP.Session.CheckForTimeout(String additional) 
at WinSCP.PatientFileStream.Wait(Int32& interval) 
at WinSCP.PatientFileStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count) 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData() 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars) 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText() 
at ProjectName.Upload(String HostName, String UName, String Password, String remotePath, String localFilePath)
```

Comment: Please post exception callstack.

Comment: at System.TimeSpan.Add(TimeSpan ts)
   at System.TimeSpan.op_Addition(TimeSpan t1, TimeSpan t2)
   at WinSCP.Session.CheckForTimeout(String additional)
   at WinSCP.PatientFileStream.Wait(Int32& interval)
   at WinSCP.PatientFileStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText()
   at ProjectName.Upload(String HostName, String UName, String Password, String remotePath, String localFilePath)

Comment: Please edit this into your question. It's not readable in a comment.

Comment: Updated in initial question. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`SessionOptions.Timeout`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#timeout) to some realistic value:

```
Timeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved the error. The code gets executed fully but if I open the path through putty, I do not see the file. Is there any mistake I am doing